# How To Fix Strange White Edges With DOF and Fog in Unity?

Tags: unity, effects, depth, image-effects, fog

I'm using global fog and the standard assets Depth Of Field script but it has a strange effect on the edges of far away objects.

How can I make the white edges along the trees blend smoothly into the fog?

[image]

Comment: Decrease DoF effect's strength, increase radius (if there are no options like that, try and implement them). Not sure how the result will be, but it should fix it in theory.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using a different depth of field shader (also in standard assets). This solved the problem. It must use a different method I guess.

[image]

Comment: You should also share the shader (if it's public resource) and a picture showing the end result so that others can benefit.